# asp.net gridview ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview

In Ajax,is there any technique exist to validate ASP.NET GridView, i.e., to check whether the GridView contains at least one row?
Any comments welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you render the GidView on the page. If I get you can check it using Javascript/jQuery on client side...

If you want to check it on the server side you have to call a method on the .aspx page using Ajax. In this case you should create a static web method on the page that check how many rows the gridview has got then you have to call that method using Ajax or jQuery

http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx